# How to access "file:///android_assets" from a unit test

Tags: android, unit-testing, webview

My application interops with a webview to make javascript calls. In my normal application I can set the webview to open, "file:///android_asset/index.html" and the webview loads fine. When I try to do the same thing from within a unit test ""file:///android_asset" does not exist.

Every example I've found has to do with using getInstrumentation().getTargetContext().getAssets().open but that returns an InputStream. InputStreams are not accepted by WebView, I need the path to the file.

How do I get the string path?

Comment: Well, there *is* no "string path". However, if the `WebView` itself is being created using the target context, you should be fine AFAIK. How are you creating this `WebView` in your test case?

Comment: I am testing code that creates a webview. It normally works with the string path up above. When I'm running it as a test, it does not. webview.loadurl tales a string value. Why is there no string value during a test?

Comment: "I am testing code that creates a webview" -- that's nice. That is not what I asked. I asked "how are you creating this WebView in your test case?". "Why is there no string value during a test?" -- I did not say that. You asked for a "string path". There is no "string path", because there is no "path". `file:///android_asset/` says "look in this package's assets", not "look in this filesystem location". All of this suggests that your `WebView` is being created with the test suite's `Context`, not the app's `Context`. Which is why I asked how you were creating the `WebView`.

Comment: The WebView is being created inside a class that takes a context. I am passing in the test's getTargetContext() and the webview is being created with that.

Comment: That's rather strange. I cannot explain your results, and I don't have a suggestion for a fix -- sorry!

Comment: Maybe the issue is something else... I am waiting for onPageFinished to fire on the webview. This is not happening. In order to wait for this I am using the CountDownLatch trick. Is it possible the thread is somehow being held up and therefore onPageFinished is never being fired. Do you know how I write a test for code the instantiates a WebView, waits for the onPageLoaded result and then continues on with the unit test?

Comment: I have never tried that, sorry.